# Adding GLSL syntax highlighting to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glsl

Is there an Eclipse plugin that adds support for GLSL files? I found something old on Google, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: He is not asking for a recommendation. He is asking if *any* GLSL editors exist for Eclipse. There are only two or three in existence, and not listed on the Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 22):

The [Eclipse Shaders](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glshaders/files/Eclipse%20Shaders%20files/Eclipse%20Plugins%20and%20Features/Eclipse_shaders_1_0_2.zip/download) plugin mentioned by Gilbert Le Blanc works for me with Eclipse Juno.

Place the contents of the "plugins" folder in your Eclipse plugins folder, and place the contents of the "features" folder in your Eclipse features folder. Then restart Eclipse.

You might need to name your shaders with the extension ".glsl", or else right click the shader file in Eclipse, ->"Open With"->"GLSL Editor"

Comment: Works with Kepler, too.

Comment: Works with Galileo as well

Comment: Works with Juno as well

Comment: Works with ADT as well

Comment: I got this working with Helios also.  I use .frag and .vert for my extensions.  In Eclipse Helios, you can map things this way: Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations.  File types: > Add... > .frag.  With .frag selected, Associated editors: > Add... > "GLSL editor".  Do the same thing with .vert and you are set!

Comment: Not sure how often this is checked, but would anyone want me to create a plugin with auto-complete?

Comment: I am not sure that link is still ok. The "glslc.zip" sourceforce downloads contains no "plugins" folder, nor a features folder.
It just contains 3 dll files (glslang.dll,msvcr80.dll,msvcp80.dll) and a glslc.exe which I am hesitant to run.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @darkflame. Perhaps those dll/exe files need to go in the dropins folder per sali's answer. In any case, I found plugins/folders under a different location: http://sourceforge.net/projects/glshaders/files/Eclipse%20Shaders%20files/Eclipse%20Plugins%20and%20Features/Eclipse_shaders_1_0_2.zip/download AND it's working on Eclipse MARS.

Comment: Yes, the ones in those folders worked perfectly.
Guess the zip is for something else and not as sinister as I suspected.

Comment: Confirmed to work with Mars as well using the method and the link described in the comment by @ChristopherBruns

Comment: can you please update the answer to work with eclipse 'neon.2' - I've installed it using an eclipse.installer, and there's no 'features' folder. Only 'plugins', and 'dropins'. I put the content of plugins inside plugins, and of features inside 'dropins' (I guess that's what's wrong) - and it doesn't work. I'm running eclipse on Ubunto. Thanks!

Comment: @Alonbs From the docs here http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html it appears you could put them under dropins/eclipse/[plugins,features]. Could you please try that and report back whether it works?

Comment: It partially worked. I did as you suggested, and it does recognize the GLSL editor (you have to associate it manually though). The syntax is indeed highlighted, but I don't get warning or errors - could it be because I'm running a 'Makefile project' using an external Makefile ?

Comment: @Alonbs I think syntax highlighting might be all this plugin actually does.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 16):

If you're looking for GLSL **ES** syntax highlighting, I've just published an eclipse plugin [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/webglsl).

Comment: Quite nice - thanks. Gets rid of the misspelled sqigglies on swizzles and the like.

Imho, it would be even better if you had a Toggle Comment binding for Ctrl+/.

Comment: how to install the plugin? Thnx

Comment: no website, no support, no documentation, plugin not work!

Comment: I'd also like to know how to install these manually :>

Comment: Just installed this plugin in Eclipse Luna (4.4), works perfectly. Thanks, petrbroz!

Comment: this is a really nice plugin. the only downside is i can't format the file in the webgl editor. is there a workaround? (for the webgl editor. i know i can open it back in a text editor/c++ editor and format. but it's just a small burden)

Comment: and you can't comment out code or other shortcuts either. it'd be good if it were just the c++ editor, with the improved highlighting.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you mean the OpenGL Shading Language, the [Eclipse CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) plugin might work well enough.

Edited to add: I probably found the same [Eclipse Shaders](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glshaders/) project on SourceForge that you found.

It appears that there is not a GLSL plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: I do mean that, but a general C or C++ parser isn't much help, since it doesn't recognise most of the keywords, types and built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Having [Eclipse Shaders](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glshaders/) downloaded, place the content of plugins and features folder in corresponding folders in :

on Linux:

```
/usr/share/eclipse/dropins/cdt/eclipse/plugins
```

on windows:

```
 in dropins folder (e.g. C:\Program Files\eclipse\dropins)
```

on OS X:

```
 in dropins folder (/Applications/eclipse/dropins/)
```